# Flask: button to update value in database

Tags: python, html, flask

so I currently pull a value from a database and display it on the screen. I have a HTML button right next to it that is supposed to increase the score on the screen by 1 every time I click it. Currently, when I click the button nothing happens. The number on the screen stays the same.

Python file

```
@app.route('/')
def layout():
    db = get_db()
    try:
        cur1 = db.execute('SELECT score FROM {tn} where name="Tyler"'.format(tn="Score"))
        score1 = cur1.fetchone()
        if request.method == 'POST':
            db.execute('UPDATE {tn} SET score=score+1 WHERE name="Tyler"'.format(tn="Score"))
            db.commit()
    except:
        flash("This person doesn't exist in our database!")
    return render_template('layout.html', score1=score1)
```

HTML file

```
  <form action="{{ url_for('layout') }}" method="post">
    <p align="center">Tyler</p>
    <div align="center">
      <tr>
        <td>{{ score1.score }}</td>
      </tr> &nbsp; &nbsp;
      <button type="button">+1</button>
    </div>
  </form>
```

Any help is appreciated. Thank you.

Edit: updated view and HTML. Same issue.

Comment: So, what happens? (And why are you interpolating the table name, especially when it's hard coded anyway?)

Comment: Whenever I click the button the number doesn't change. It just stays at zero (default in table). I plan on taking a lot of the hard-coding out once I have basic functionality so that's why you see some sprinkles of interpolation.

Answer (score 0):

Your two view functions are mapped to the same route; but a URL can only be served by one view.

Either map your increaseScore1 function to a different route, or combine the logic in one function which checks if the method is POST and updates the score if so, otherwise just displays it.

Comment: That makes a lot of sense, and thank you for your answer. I updated my code and tried it, but got the same issue.